Google run altering a request payload in very strange way
I’m experiencing a strange issue where my JSON payload is being distorted when deployed on Google Cloud Run, but the same code works perfectly fine on Heroku and localhost. I'm using Laravel 11 and PHP. Here’s what my payload looks like before and after the distortion:
[
    {
        "id": "15758",
        "product_price": "5"
    }
]

To this
{
    "0": {
        "id": "15758",
        "product_price": "5"
    },
    "q": "/v1/products/variants" // this is strangely added by google, it is the URL of the request endpoint
}

Strangely google run adds a key "q" with the url of the request endpoint.

The issue turned out to be from Nginx
